# Conflict with createBottomTabNavigator and createStackNavigator in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have started learning react-native and I'm experiencing some issues. I don't seem to be able to use both components (createBottomTabNavigator and createStackNavigator). Export default can only be used once and I would like to render both components(at the moment only one or the other is rendering).
It would be great to get some help. thanks

```
Navigation.js
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import Search from '../Components/Search'
import Favourites from '../Components/Favourites'
import FilmDetail from '../Components/FilmDetail'

const SearchStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Search: {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Search Film'
    }
  },
  FilmDetail: {
    screen: FilmDetail,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Film Details'
    }
  }
})
const MoviesTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Search: {
    screen: Search
  },
  Favourites: {
    screen: Favourites
  }
})

export default createAppContainer(MoviesTabNavigator)
```

I'm aware that I'm not using the latest version of React-Native

```
Package.json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-cli": "^3.28.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.5.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.13",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Store from './Store/configureStore'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <Navigation/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting your screen will solve your problem. I assume you want **SearchStackNavigator** within **MoviesTabNavigator**. Do something like below

```js
const MoviesTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Search: {
    screen: SearchStackNavigator
  },
  Favourites: {
    screen: Favourites
  }
})

export default createAppContainer(MoviesTabNavigator)
```

Answer (score 0):

To navigate between stacks and land in a specific screen use:

navigation.navigate('Stack', {screen: 'screenName')

Error seems to be that Search is not referring to your SearchStackNavigator but your "Search" component you import at the top.

Nested Stacks are possible. I'd recommend taking a look here: [Master React Navigation 5](https://www.reactnativeschool.com/master-react-navigation-v5/tab-nav-basics)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use react-navigation 5.x and follow this example:

SearchStackNavigator:

```
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const SearchStackNavigator = () => 
  <Stack.Navigator>
     <Stack.Screen
        name="Search"
        component={Search}
     />
     <Stack.Screen
        name="FilmDetail"
        component={FilmDetail}
     />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

MoviesTabNavigator:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import SearchStackNavigator from "./SearchStackNavigator";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MoviesTabNavigator = () => 
   <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
         name="Search"
         component={SearchStackNavigator} />
       <Tab.Screen
         name="Other tab"
         component={OTHER STACK OR SCREEN HERE} />
   </Tab.Navigator>
```

**react-navigation docs**:

[bottom-tab docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/)

[stack-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/)

Comment: Thanks, next project I'll move to v5.